# does passing a collection to a function means the function can change the collection's elements?

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I actually know the answer to the question (I think) but I don't know the reason...

So, I know that if I have a class like the following:

```
class Man
{
    public string Name;
    public int Height;

    public Man() { }
    public Man(string i_name, int i_height)
    {
        Name = i_name;
        Height = i_height;
    }

}
```

And I have the following Program class (with main function):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Man g = new Man("greg", 175);

        //assigning null to g inside the function.
        p.ChangeMan(g);


        Console.WriteLine(g == null? "the function changed g out side the function" : "the function did not change g out side the function");
        //the output of course is that the function did not change g outside the function.

        //now I am creating a list of Man and adding 5 Man instances to it.

        List<Man> manList = new List<Man>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            manList.Add(new Man("Gadi" + i.ToString(), 10 * i));
        }

        //assigning null to the list insdie the function
        p.ChangeList(manList);
        Console.WriteLine(manList == null ? "the function changed the list out side the function" : "the function did not change the list out side the function");
        //the output of cousre again is the function did not change the list out side the function

        //now comes the part I dont understand...


        p.ChangeManInAList(manList);

        Console.WriteLine("list count = " + manList.Count());
        //count is now 6.

        Console.WriteLine(manList[0] == null ? "the function changed the element out side the function" : "the function did not change the element out side the function");
        //the out again - the function did not change...


    }

    public void ChangeMan(Man g)
    {
        g = null;
    }

    public void ChangeManInAList(IList<Man> gadiList)
    {
        Man g = gadiList.First<Man>();
        g = null;
        Console.WriteLine(g == null? "g is null" : "g is not null");

        gadiList.Add(new Man("a new gadi", 200));
        Console.WriteLine("list count = " + gadiList.Count());
    }

    public void ChangeList(List<Man> list)
    {
        list = null;
    }


}
```

I am assigning null to the first element of the list + adding one Man to the list. I expected that if I can add to the list, I can also change the elements, but I saw different...

I was able to add a Man to the list but could not assign null to one of the elements, how come? I know the list is passed by value so I can not change the list itself (like assigning null to it), but I can add to it? and can not assign null to the elements? are they being passed by val as well?

will be happy for some good and clear explanation :)

Comment: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: "Console.WriteLine(g == null ? "the function changed the list"
shouldn't be
"Console.WriteLine(manList == null ? "the function changed the list"?

Comment: yes, you are right, but the output is the same :)

Comment: When you do `g = null` you are not changing the `Man` *referred to* by `g` to `null`, you are just setting the *local variable `g`* to `null` so it no longer refers to the original `Man`. That does not affect the `Man` or the `List` containing it.

Comment: Look at it like a helium balloon on a string. You've got the string (your reference variable) in your hand. You show the string to your friend (the function) who follows the string up to the balloon (the object instance) and ties his own string to it (the parameter variable). Then your friend cuts his string (assigns null to his variable). This does not affect your string or the balloon. Your friend simply doesn't have a string attached to it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your point of confusion:

```
 Man g = gadiList.First<Man>();
 g = null;
```

What you are essentially doing is getting a `Man` out of the list and assigning it to the local variable `g`.
Then, you assign a different value to the variable `g`.

**At no point here did you change the value of any member of the list**, you simply changed the value which the variable `g` refers to.

Let's try to compare it to this example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
b = 3;
//you wouldn't expect `a` to be 3 now, would you?
```

In order to change the value of the list item, you would need to explicitly set the list index to a different value:

```
Man g = gadiList.First<Man>();
gadiList[gadiList.IndexOf(g)] = null;

//or specifically in this case:
gadiList[0] = null;
```

Comment: that leads to another question:
so, i saw i can null my elements, is there a way for me to protect it?
I dont want the user who provides a function to me accidently null my elements...

Comment: @JimmyBoy Look into `ReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: @JimmyBoy What do you mean? You can only "null your elements" by doing `gadiList[i] = null;`

Comment: I have a question - why assigning null in the ChangeMan method doesn't change g variable in Main method, while if we put there g.Name = "greg2" it does?

Comment: @Rotem - Thank you , i indeed changed my code and saw exactly what you mean, my bad (silly mistake)
i will read about the readOnlyCollection :) sounds like what i am looking for. thanks again

Comment: A ReadOnlyCollection can't be modified by the function, but also can't be modified by your own code. If you're worried about your object being used improperly by the function, don't pass it. Find a way to pass just the necessary data instead.

Comment: @JC That's exactly what `ReadOnlyCollection` is for - it's a read-only **wrapper** around a regular collection.

Answer (score 0):

When you get element from list you get new reference to list item.
So as a result you get two references: one (private reference in list object), your reference.
When you set your reference to null it do not affect reference in list object. You reference became null, but private list reference remains the same.